# Inaccessible tty still has some bash processes

Tags: bash, macos, tty, ps

This is a very strange situation. I'm on OS X 10.11.6

I have an old tty still hanging around (`ttys001`) but I don't know how to access it and why its still there. It simply does not have any window on the os x desktop. I'm on ttys000.

```
$ tty
/dev/ttys000
```

This means I'm currently on ttys000

```
$ w
22:01  up 15 days,  7:47, 3 users, load averages: 1.65 1.43 1.45
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
Sidharth console  -                30Jul16 15days -
Sidharth s000     -                13:48       - w
Sidharth s001     -                Thu13    9:12 -bash
```

I can understand the login from console (it happens automatically) but where is this s001 (i.e. `ttys001`) coming from -- I can't switch to it -- I don't see any os x terminal windows corresponding to ttys001.

```
USER       PID  PPID  PGID   SESS JOBC STAT   TT       TIME COMMAND
root     30994 30725 30994      0    0 Ss   s000    0:00.04 login -pf    Sidharth
Sidharth 30995 30994 30995      0    1 S    s000    0:00.33 -bash
root     32409 30995 32409      0    1 R+   s000    0:00.01 ps aj
root     26065     1 26065      0    0 Ss+  s001    0:00.04 login -pfl Sidharth /bin/bash -c exec -la bash /bin/bash
Sidharth 26066 26065 26065      0    0 S+   s001    0:00.28 -bash
Sidharth 29465 26066 26065      0    0 S+   s001    0:00.00 -bash
```

These are the various processes with associated ttys. Again, I can't understand the life of me what 26065, 26066 and 29465 (all associated with 26065) are doing/why are they there.

Some observations: the parent of 30944 is 30725 which is the Mac Terminal application (this makes sense). But equally interesting is that the parent of 26065 (corresponding to `login -pfl Sidharth /bin/bash -c exec -la bash /bin/bash` is launchd i.e. pid 1)

I've noticed stuff like this before: there is usually an old ttys but its not visible.

- Nope I'don't have any additional tabs open in my os x terminal program that could cause this
- My question is this: Why is my ttys001 inaccessible? How do I "get to" ttys001

Comment: I'd probably use `kill -1 29465 26066` to get rid of the two `bash` processes and the `login` will then leave on its own.  If HUP (signal 1) doesn't work, you can try 15 (TERM) and if that fails too, then 9 (KILL).  If that doesn't work, reboot. You might be able to do something with a custom program that opens `/dev/ttys001` and then launches a shell with that as the standard input, output and error.  But you'd still have the other processes running — potentially interfering with what you're typing in the recently launched shell — and they'll not vanish until you manage to get them to exit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks... the issue is not really what to do with them, rather _why are they there_ and why did they arise in the first place...

Comment: In your current terminal window, have you used the Window option (in the menu bar) to see whether that terminal shows up in the list of terminals?  You can use the command key (⌘) and a number to switch between terminals. I have 4 terminal windows open, it seems — one of them hadn't been used in 25 days, which kinda surprised me.  The last `ls` command showing was indeed of a very old version of a directory which has changed a lot since back then.

Comment: Assuming that the ⌘1 or ⌘2 mechanism does nothing, then something fairly weird happened.  It probably isn't feasible to deduce what happened; it probably wouldn't happen again.  As I said, I'd get rid of it and only worry if it happened persistently.  Maybe you've got an intruder on your machine?  (Not very likely, but funnier things have been known.)

Comment: Yes -- there are no open tabs and windows of Terminal other than the one I'm in. The parent process of the bash-es in question is _not_ Terminal. (See my observations on the parent processes.)

Comment: I have noticed this happen before also...

Comment: OK; so the parent Terminal application died and the child got inherited by the init process.  Why did Terminal die?  No idea.  You might find something in the Console log, but you probably wouldn't.  Weird stuff happens occasionally — maybe it was an anti-muon neutrino that interacted with your system, to the chagrin of physicists everywhere who were looking for the particle and have routinely failed to detect it?

Comment: Odd that it happened before.  I just tried a `kill -1` on my terminal process; it killed all the open terminal windows (no problem; they were all at command prompt).  I restarted it w/o problem.  That was terminal dying under control.  Using `kill -9` on the new Terminal process was equally effective in killing all the windows.  I don't know if there's a reasonable way to kill the terminal process without the children being killed too; I can't think of one offhand.  Do you leave processes in some weird hung state (being traced by a debugger)?  Pretty far-fetched, but straws are being clutched.

Comment: Using `kill -6` got me an invitation to report the problem to Apple (declined; it isn't their fault that Terminal got a signal 6 — SIGABRT).  No dice.

Comment: No debugging was happening so we can eliminate that option. This is at least the 2nd time I've noticed "zombie" like ttys -- listed in a `ps a` but otherwise inaccessible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120922/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-sid-kshatriya).